# GRE expected value problem

Tags: probability

Karen is playing a game in which she will choose a ball from a bag containing $10$ balls, each of which is labeled with a different integer from $1$ to $10$. If she chooses a ball labeled, $1,2,$ or $3$, she will lost $10$ points. If she chooses a ball labeled $4$ or $5$, she will gain $5$ points. If she chooses a ball labeled $6,7,8,9,$ or $10$, she will gain $20$ points. What's the expected value of the number of points Karen will gain by choosing a ball at random from the bag?

My approach as since we know that the probability of losing $10$ points is $\frac{3}{10}$, earning $5$ points is $\frac{2}{10}$ and $20$ points is $\frac{5}{10}$.

So we have the calculation as follows, $$E(x)=\frac{3}{10} \cdot (-10) + \frac{2}{10} \cdot 5 + \frac{5}{10} \cdot 20 = 8$$

But the answer is $9$, not sure whether the way that I calculated is wrong or my interpretation is wrong, or even the answer is wrong. Have been long time for not doing expected value problems, any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: I also get the answer $8$, via the same calculation you performed.

Comment: You are correct.  Whatever source you are looking at has a typo or mistake.

Comment: One way to make the answer $9$ would be to have  "If she chooses a ball labeled $4$ or $5$, she will gain $10$ points."